# Why is Hochschild cohomology just a group and not a module?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

This is probably a very basic question in Hochschild theory.

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be a $k$-algebra (which is not commutative).

If $M$ is an $A$-bimodule, then the $n$-th Hochschild cohomology of $A$ with coefficients in $M$ is given by

$Ext^n_{A^e}(A,M)$.

Why is this not an $A^e$-module? First, both $A$ and $M$ are left $A^e$-modules, so this $Ext$ is defined, and is an abeliean group. But can't I also view $A$ as a right $A^e$-module? so that this is has a structure of an $A^e$-module?

Comment: As the answer below explains, it's true that the Hochschild cohomology groups aren't $A^e$-modules, however you can give them various other module structures. For example they are $Z(A)$-modules, where $Z(A)$ is the centre of $A$, and therefore when $A$ is commutative they are $A$-modules. You can also give them the structure of a $k$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't have an $A^e$-module structure, because the left and right actions of $A^e$ on $A$ don't commute unless $A$ is commutative, so $A$ is not an $A^e-(A^e)^{op}$ bimodule.

That doesn't prove that there's not an $A^e$-module structure defined some other way, but to see that this isn't the case, consider the example $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{H}$, the quaternions, considered as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Then $H^0(A,A)=\mathbb{R}$, the centre of $A$, which can't have an action of $A^e$, or even of $A$, as $A$ doesn't have any modules with real dimension 1.

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured it out by myself since I asked the question, but it is always reassuring to know that I got this right.

Comment: Please let explain what  does it mean $A^e$-module?